# What are the guidelines for tag descriptions?

Tags: discussion

If one wants to write a tag description on the wiki, what should be put in it?

Comment: When you go to edit a tag wiki it gives you a blurb plus this link: [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)